# Долгий ответ простого запроса. Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Всем доброго времени суток, помогите разобраться что происходит с базой, при запросе:

```
select sum (number) from energy 
where datetime between to_date ('7.03.17 9:00:00','d.mm.yy hh24:mi:ss') and to_date ('7.03.17 9:01:00','d.mm.yy hh24:mi:ss')
```

Время от 7 до 15 секунд, но это еще не конец, при попытке перезапустить базу командами shutdown normal - команда просто виснет и ничего не происходит, один раз правда остановилась но после не запустилась сообщив об ошибке ora-27100. Перезапуск сервера решил проблему максимум на 30 мин. Всем спасибо за помощь

Comment: Вы хотите сказать что Oracle согласился на запрос с SUM() без GROUP BY?

Comment: 1. Из информации неясно сколько строк должны попасть в выборку - может быть, из миллионы. Неясно, есть ли индекс на столбце datetime. 2. Shutdown, он же shutdown normal ждёт пока отключатся все текущие сессии. 3. GROUP BY, конечно же, не нужен, если только аналитические/групповые функции в результате выборки.

Comment: @hinotf 1 - за период 1 минута должно выгрузить 60 значений, тоесть запись в бд каждая секунда. 2- индекса нет. Как Остановить базу сразу ?

Comment: Попробуйте создать индекс. Shutdown immediate рвёт все сессии и останавливает базу. Тут почитайте https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/start003.htm#ADMIN11156

Comment: @hinotf создал индекс время сократилось на 2сек. В другой базе я за год выгрузки имею 2сек ожидания. В чем может быть еще проблема ?

Comment: Нужно сравнить два плана выполнения. Почитайте в сети, как их создать.

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос скрипт создания таблицы с указанием всех ключей.